# Search results (from external source) unclickable

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, sharepoint-on-prem, bug

In SharePoint Sever 2019 (on premise) I crawled a shared disk (let's call it `\\fileserver\folder`) using Search Service Application (added an additional content source and did full crawl). When I search "all sites" through SharePoint, results show up for files on `\\fileserver\folder`. When I hover over a result, my browser shows the correct path in the bottom left (it says `file://fileserver/folder/filename`) and when I right-click and choose "copy link address" I get the desired result on my clipboard. However, when I click the result, nothing happens. When I right-click a result and choose "open link", a blank page opens with empty address bar. Tried in multiple browsers; results still not clickable.

There are other bugs. For one, the search result title is oftentimes not the filename, but something else, and I even have results which say `*NONE`. Below the sear result title, it says "on" and then nothing (I'd expect it say "on \fileserver\folder\subfolder" or something like that).

[image: Empty "on" fields (file location) for search results]

It goes without saying the search feature is disappointing. Even the pagination system is stupid: you don't see in advance how many pages of results there are; you just see `< 1 2 >` and when you click on `2`, it turns out there's a third page, and so on.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/file-links-not-working-on-chrome-or-edge-chromium/m-p/1288891

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks, that explains part of the problem. But why is the "on " field empty?"